# Count Single Words in Python

Tags: python, list

So I need to count individual words (specifically red and blue) in a python inputted list.
However, it cannot be for instance redish or bluemaybe.
Here's what I've done (I've tried if loops to catch it but hasn't worked.)

```
r = 0
b = 0
cars = []
car = input("Cars: ")
cars.append(car)
car.split()
r = car.count('red')
b = car.count('blue')
print("red:",r)
print("blue:",b)
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Why not split it into words (there's a SO question with a good answer how to do that), then feed those words into a `collections.Counter` and just get the count from that?

Comment: Manufacturers don't call their car colours 'red' and 'blue', they use words like Cherry, Matador, and Tahiti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works.

```
# replace by 'carsStr = input("Cars: ")' if you wish
carsStr = "rad blue blueish redish red blue red" 
# str.split() returns a list of strings, never in-place
cars = carsStr.split()
r = cars.count('red')
b = cars.count('blue')
print("red:",r)
print("blue:",b)
```

Here are your mistakes:

- Doing `cars.append(car)` and then `car.split()` doesn't "expand" the `car` string in the `cars` list.
- `car.split()` doesn't happen in-place, it returns a list of strings. In your case, that list is lost since you don't assign it to a variable.
- You also never reuse the `cars` list.

If you wan't a more complete counting tool see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a loop to iterate through the list then return your values
Split and append aren't necessary. When faced with a coding problem, try to find the simplest answer and the most concise without sacrificing any substance.

```
for words in cars:
    cars.count('red', 'blue')
    return whatever_you_want
```